# How can i change focus from one object to next preferred object which i want in appleTvOS development project in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, tvos

Actually, I'm developing an **AppleTV** project in swift3. I faced some problem with **focus change** using the remote. Is there any way to change focus from one object to another object which I want. I can not move one object to another when it is not exact alignment(left, right, up, down). I tried below code but not working,and i am [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv61u.jpg)also giving one screenshot where i wan to move focus from pink button to red dot button but i can't.plz provide me some code for this.

```
override var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    get {
    return preferredFocusedView1
    } 
}
```

Comment: you need to use UIFocusGuide if the focusable ui is not aligned

Answer (score 1):

In tvOS, the Focus Engine can only navigate using simple paths: up, down, right or left.

For more complex navigations paths you need to define a Focus Guide:

You can find the documentation of UIFocusGuide in the following link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifocusguide

And a good tutorial about this issue here: 
https://medium.com/@thomalexandre/using-uifocusguide-on-tvos-352e7afba132

Comment: I tried bellow code but not working when i am trying to move focus to the next button just few left side of the previous button bellow(not exactly bellow)    


    verride func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator)